# SQL : Running select statement for local string variable

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is a case where I am running **SQL select statement** on `local string`.
If I run normal select query for my tables then it works.

```
select * from tablesname
```

**But if I have following case :**

```
declare @string nvarchar(400)

set @string = N'from tablesname'
```

Now if I run `select * from @string` , it is not working as expected.

Please suggest me for to resolve this problem, since I want to run the select statement in this way only.
If I should try some other way, then suggest me that.

Thanks,
Tausif.

Comment: set @string = N'from tablesname' ?

Comment: It's better practice to make a stored procedure/tvf/whatever to select from each table, rather than one that selects from any (via a parameter and dynamic sql). I'm guessing that's what you're trying to achieve anyway...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using MySQL since your question is tagged with it, although this `set @string = N'from tablesname'` suggests, that you're using MS SQL Server or something:

```
SET @yourDynamicTablename = 'yourTable';
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', @yourDynamicTablename );
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

You might want to put that in a stored procedure.

Your attempt wasn't working, because you can't select from a string. For further reading about prepared statements, which are also useful for avoiding SQL injection attacks, have a look in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).