# SQL Server: How to write and execute a prepared statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, prepared-statement, dynamic-sql

In MySQL, we can generate the prepared statement using `PreparedStatement`.

I want to achieve the same functionality in SQL script. How to create the prepared statement and how to execute it? Please provide an example for that.

Comment: If you would have asked **me** instead of the other one answering this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11982501/sql-running-select-statement-for-local-string-variable, I could have told you that, also. I think, when you use a site extensively it's also a matter of politeness to learn how to use it.

Comment: While there are certainly issues w/ the OP's participation on SO, is it _really_ "difficult to tell what is being asked here?"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would suggest using [`sp_executesql`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) over [`exec`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) for most dynamic SQL.  `sp_executesql` is similar to MySQL's [`EXECUTE...USING`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) in that it can take parameters rather than only concatenated strings, thus giving you a good defense against SQL injection. `sp_executesql` also allows SQL Server to reuse the query plan for more efficient querying.  Here's an example:

```
exec sp_executesql
    @statement = N'select * from sys.databases where name = @dbname or database_id = @dbid',
    @parameters = N'@dbname sysname, @dbid int',
    @dbname = N'master',
    @dbid = 1
```

Some more info and examples can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175170.aspx).